# jQuery if CSS display none change select list value

Tags: jquery

I have some conditional fields, so when a user changes a field a new field gets to be displayed, what I want to do is to remove the value of previously selected field which is now display none.

So I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
  if($('.field-type-list-integer').css('display') == 'none') {
    $(this).closest("select option[disabled]").attr("selected", "selected");
  }
});
```

the issue is that it clears the value of every field and disregards the `.css('display') == 'none'` condition.

Here's the HTML Structure:

```
    <div class="field-type-list-integer" id="edit-field-year-build-miladi" style="display: block;" checked="checked">
<div class="form-type-select">
    <select id="edit-field-year-build-miladi-und" name="field_year_build_miladi[und]" class="form-select valid" placeholder="year">
    <option value="_none" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">YEAR</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: There are many many things wrong in your code, the first one is that `this` is referring to `document` in that context, so...

Comment: sorry that extra ) weren't suppose to be there, just got it fixed. but still the issue is still there, also A.Wolff thx for your comment, I'm not good at jQuery as you can see, so can you help me out here then please?

Comment: Sorry but for me your code and expected behaviour doesn't make sense. You want to check a disabled and hidden option element, why??? Aren't you looking instead to reset `select` element?

Comment: because on form submit, the data will be submitted, even though the user no longer needs it.

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem  You are asking question regarding workaround you think would fix your issue, not regarding your former problem. You'd need instead to disabled `select` element. It should be something like that instead: http://jsfiddle.net/bb9qmk8t/   Note that in your posted HTML markup, you aren't closing `select` element. That's said, you shouldn't use kind of placeholder for `select` element but a label instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that this is not the element you expect. In you code it is just the `document`.

In the case you have more the one `.field-type-list-integer`you can loop it by using `each`. Then you can simply use this to do exactly what you want to do.

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('.field-type-list-integer').each(function(){
        if ($(this).css('display') === 'none') {
            $(this).find("select option").removeAttr("selected");    
            $(this).find("select option[disabled]").attr("selected", "selected");        
        }
    });
});
```

Also note, that you have to remove the selected option manually to avoid multiple selected options.

See this fiddle to see the code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/h6cbwvc9/

Comment: `The problem is that this is not the element you expect. In you code it is just the body` It is the `document` object, not the `body` element ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I dont see what exactly is happening in fiddle, what I have in mind is if user change the value of a certain field, another field becomes display none, and if previously user entered any value in that select list, I want it to be cleared and set to _none

Comment: @Sohail Doesn't what you want is the selected element value not be send on form submit? That's quite different behaviour

Comment: well yes, that's the end result I'm after, it can be set on form submit, but nevertheless I need the hidden select fields to be cleared of any values

Comment: thanks to you both Allanon and A. Wolff, I have it to be triggered on form submit and it works just fine

Comment: your welcome :-) and thanks to @A.Wolff for the hint that its `document`, not `body`. Just corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really get what you're doing but did you try with the [:hidden](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector?

EDIT: As @Allanon said, you have to use a loop (each).
Just to complete his answer with my initial idea, you should be able to do that.

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('.field-type-list-integer:hidden').each(function(){
        $(this).find("select option").removeAttr("selected");    
        $(this).find("select option[disabled]").attr("selected", "selected");
    });
});
```

And see the live demo here http://jsfiddle.net/h6cbwvc9/1/

Comment: Please consider adding a comment instead of posting an answer when you don't plan on actually *answering* the question.

Comment: yep I did try that but still, no proper result

Comment: Sorry @D4V1D but I can't comment the first post because I don't have 50 reputation has SO told me :(

Comment: @PeterPan666: Still, not having 50 points rep doesn't mean you can use answers as comments. [Have a look at this meta topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252133/50-reputation-points-to-make-comments).

Comment: @D4V1D I don't get it, should I suggest an edit then?

Comment: @PeterPan666: You should try to *answer* questions you can answer to reach this 50 rep-points threshold when you'll be able to make comments. Another way to reach this threshold is, indeed, to suggests edits (+2 rep points per approval).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @PeterPan666: I did read them. The difference is that the other ones are just comments, but my text originates from the review process after your answer was flagged as not constructive.

Comment: No problem @Reeno , should I delete it?

Comment: Give the guy a break :D

Comment: No no, it's a real question. I'm pretty new to SO, I'm just asking habits and customs ;)

Comment: @PeterPan666 You should extend your answer to a complete answer whch is understandable and usable without any link. You may add links for reference, but your answer should still be valid and usable if the link is broken anytime.